# Confidence Regions for NonLinearFit with “complicated” integral model

Tags: fitting

I have a set of data $y_i (z_i)$ with errors $\Delta y_i$, that can be found here

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lsnoqgi5wumgxb/Cat3_0mod.txt)

Thus first, I call  the data

```
dataSN = Import["Cat3_0mod.txt", "Table"];
sigdata = dataSN[[All, 4]];
lendata = Length[zdata];

fitSN = Table[{dataSN[[i, 2]], dataSN[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, lendata}];
```

I want to fit these data to a complicated model

$$
Y(z) = 5\log \Bigl((1+z)\int_0^z \frac{dz'}{a+bz'+cz'^2}\Bigr)+25;
$$

With help of a previous post [NonLinearFit with "complicated" integral model](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44718/nonlinearfit-with-complicated-integral-model)

I used 'NonLinerFit'

```
ModelSN1[z_] = 
  Simplify[5 Log[10, (1 + z) Integrate[1/(a + b x + c x^2), {x, 0, z}]] + 25, 
    Assumptions -> {z > 0, -b^2 + 4 a c > 0}];

fit = 
  NonlinearModelFit[fitSN, {ModelSN1[z], -b^2 + 4 a c > 0}, 
   {{a, 0.000254}, {b, .000016}, {c, .000016}}, z, Weights -> 1/(sigdata)^2];
```

Even the fit looks fine

[image]

The reality is that the fit is complex

[image]

I Have some problems making the fit

1. Even I put conditions over the parameters $a,b,c$ the fitted model is complex. I tried to put as condition that the whole term inside $\log$ should be positive, but it does not work.
2. I want to make confidence regions on this fit using

   ```
    band1SN[z_] = fit["MeanPredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.68]; 
    band2SN[z_] = fit["MeanPredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95];
   ```

but *Mathematica* does not make it, an error related with the fact of assuming a constrained model appears. Of course, if the fit is complex, the confidence regions could not be calculated. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Took another look at this. I don't really have in answer but this may help if anyone want to play with it:

```
    data = #[[{2, 3}]] & /@ Import["Cat3_0mod.txt", "Table"]
```

Break the integral into parts with different assumptions and assemble as a `Piecewise` function: ( results for assumptions `-b^2 + 4 a c > 0` and `-b^2 + 4 a c <0` are the same if we make the `Abs` substitution shown )

```
g3[z_] = Simplify[
      5 Log[10, (1 + z) Integrate[1/(a + b x + c x^2), {x, 0, z}]] + 25, 
      Assumptions -> {z > 0, -b^2 + 4 a c > 0}] /. -b^2 + 4 a c -> Abs[-b^2 + 4 a c]
g1[z_] = Simplify[
     5 Log[10, (1 + z) Integrate[
     1/(a + b x + (b^2/4/a) x^2), {x, 0, z}]] + 25, 
     Assumptions -> {z > 0, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
g0[z_] = Simplify[
     5 Log[10, (1 + z) Integrate[1/(a + b x), {x, 0, z}]] + 25, 
     Assumptions -> {z > 0, a > 0, b > 0}]
g[z_] = Piecewise[ {
   { g0[z] , c == 0} , 
   {g1[z] , -b^2 + 4 a c == 0 }, {g3[z], True}}]
```

Now do a fit with constraints (this still needs a good inital guess)

```
   fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, {g[z], {a > 0, b > 0, c >= 0}},
        {{a, 0.0002}, {b, 0.0001}, {c, 0.0001}}, z]
```

Now take the result an plug it back in as a start point for an unconstrained fit:

```
   {a0, b0, c0} = {a, b, c} /. fit["BestFitParameters"]
   fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, g[z], {{a, a0}, {b, b0}, {c, c0}}, z]
```

This last fit finishes quickly with no warnings..

```
   fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {0.000233781, 0.0000547078, 0.000137895}

```
   Show[{ListPlot[data], Plot[fit[z], {z, 0, 1.4}, PlotStyle -> Red]}, 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Unfortunately after all that

```
  fit["MeanPredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> .99]
```

still gives an error:

> "The function value ... is not a number at {a,b,c} =  {0.000233781,0.0000547078,0.000137895}

Note the "offending" parameter set is close to the best fit set (It is actually slightly different but not so much so that the sign of `b^2-4 a c` changes) so I have no idea whats going on there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your model might be unnecessarily complex.  Consider taking the logs of both the dependent and independent variables:

```
ListLogLogPlot[fitSN, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"z", "y"}]
```

[image: Data on a log log scale]

A simple linear model looks like a good candidate model (shown with 95% single prediction intervals):

```
lm = LinearModelFit[Log[fitSN], z, z];
lm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {3.787583704711951,0.061443756024911325} *)

spb = lm["SinglePredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> .95] /. z -> Log[z];
{zmin, zmax} = MinMax[fitSN[[All, 1]]];
Show[ListLogLogPlot[fitSN, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"z", "y"}],
 LogLogPlot[{Exp[lm[Log[z]]], Exp[spb]},
  {z, zmin, zmax}]]
```

[image: Data and fit on log scale]

The residual plots don't look great (meaning the assumptions of normality and constant variance) but are much better than what has been proposed by the original model:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{lm["PredictedResponse"], lm["FitResiduals"]}],
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Predicted response", "Residual"}]
Show[Histogram[lm["FitResiduals"], Automatic, "PDF", Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"Residual", "Density"}],
 Plot[PDF[
   NormalDistribution[0, StandardDeviation[lm["FitResiduals"]]], x],
  {x, -0.02, 0.02}]]
```

[image: Histogram of residuals]
[image: Predicted vs residual]

Finally, below is the fitted curve on the original scale:

```
Show[ListPlot[fitSN], Plot[{Exp[lm[Log[z]]], Exp[mpb], Exp[spb]},
  {z, Min[fitSN[[All, 1]]], Max[fitSN[[All, 1]]]}], Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"z", "y"}]
```

[image: Fit and data on original scale]

***Update***

Using all of the work that @george2079 has down in his answer, the linear fit can be compared to the nonlinear fit.

```
(* Linear fit *)
lm = LinearModelFit[Log[data], z, z]
(* Nonlinear fit *)
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, g[z], {{a, a0}, {b, b0}, {c, c0}}, z]

{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[data[[All, 2]]]
ListPlot[{Transpose[{fit["PredictedResponse"], Exp[lm["PredictedResponse"]]}],
  {{ymin, ymin}, {ymax, ymax}}}, Joined -> {False, True}, PlotRange -> All,
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Predicted(Nonlinear)", "Predicted(Linear)"}]
```

[image: Nonlinear vs linear fit]

We can look at more detail using the differences in the fit vs the nonlinear fit:

```
ListPlot[{Transpose[{fit["PredictedResponse"],
    fit["PredictedResponse"] - Exp[lm["PredictedResponse"]]}],
  {{ymin, 0}, {ymax, 0}}}, Joined -> {False, True}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Predicted(Nonlinear)", "Predicted(Nonlinear)-Predicted(Linear)"}]
```

[image: Prediction differences vs nonlinear prediction]

So we see that the linear fit is generally within plus-or-minus 0.02 of the nonlinear fit.  (As to whether the fits are essentially/practically identical is a subject matter call and not a statistical decision.)

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer dealt with an attempt to be convincing that a linear fit (using the logs of both dependent and independent variables) is possibly a better approach.  Here I attempt to answer the original question.

@george2079 did all of the work in his answer.  All we have to do is remove the `Abs` function from the definition of `g3` and use good starting values:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   25 + (5 Log[-((2 (1 + z) (ArcTan[b/Sqrt[-b^2 + 4 a c]] - ArcTan[(b + 2 c z)/Sqrt[-b^2 + 4 a c]]))/Sqrt[-b^2 + 4 a c])])/Log[10],
   {{a, 0.000234}, {b, 0.0000547}, {c, 0.000138}}, z];
Plot[{fit[z], Evaluate[fit["SinglePredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95]]},
 {z, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Gray, Gray}]
```

[image: Single prediction confidence bands and prediction]

I've used `"SinglePredictionBands"` rather than `"MeanPredictionBands"` because the mean prediction bands are so close to the predicted curve that they are hard to see.

I believe the issue that causes the problem is that when using `Abs` the algorithm for finding the prediction bands (probably the Delta Method) takes the derivative of the function with respect to `a`, `b`, and `c` and can't handle the derivative of `Abs`.

In short, it pays to have really good starting values.  Or stated another way:  It's always good to know the answer ahead of time.